# MySql group by columns and assign them a unique group_id

Tags: mysql, database, datagrip

Basically, there is an abstract task on removing duplicates from db, which linked by it's id with several other tables...
I need to assign for each repeating row in table a unique group_id as max(id) of existing row. Please help

My question in picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVYG1.png

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the entities (to find the group ids) at first and then update the `group_id` of entities.

Example:

```
UPDATE `t`,
    (SELECT `name`, `surname`, MAX(`id`) AS `group_id` FROM `t`
     WHERE 1 GROUP BY CONCAT(`name`, `surname`)) AS `t1`
SET `t`.`group_id` = `t1`.`group_id`
WHERE `t`.`name` = `t1`.`name` AND `t`.`surname` = `t1`.`surname`
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me. Thank you. Can you recommend some sort of book or resource where persons like me can learn such advanced queries?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any good book. Basically you just need a basic knowledge and logical thinking. (-;